# using md5 and salt with j security check

Tags: tomcat, passwords, salt, realm, j-security-check

Right now I am using j security check and md5 to authenticate my jsp pages. I would like to salt the password before I store it into the database. Due to restricted access at school, I do not have rights to create a trigger to inject some salt. Is there any other way to do this?

here is my realm:

```
<Realm 
    className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" 
    driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://someurl"
    connectionName="name" 
    connectionPassword="password" 
    userTable="name.users" 
    userNameCol="user_name" 
    userCredCol="user_password" 
    userRoleTable="name.users"
    roleNameCol="role"
    digest="MD5"
    />
```

Comment: What do you mean you are using `j_security_check`? You mean you are using container managed authentication? What server are you using? How is authentication configured for this application?

Comment: I am making a jsp app and using a glassfish v.7 server running it. So i set up my login pages whose actions are j_security_check and then I placed security constraints around my servlets.

Comment: Can you configure the "realm" that is used for your application? Or do you at least know what realm is in use?

Comment: I added the realm to original question.

Comment: Okay, did you mean Tomcat 7.0, or Glassfish?

Comment: It is a little odd that the folks at Tomcat did not consider salts or iterations which are both pretty commonplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickly said : "No, you can't. At least, not Simply"

In fact, digests are handled by `public static final Digest(String credentials, String algorithm,String   encoding)` method in `org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase` class from which your `JDBCRealm` class inherits. This `Digest` method calls directly [MessageDigest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) instance which can be used only with "MD5", "SHA-1" and "MD2" I think. So, you can't do anything to your password before or after applying your MD5 algortihm

But, you can [implement a provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html) to have the algorithm you want. But I warn you, that's not so simple.

And by the way, I'd personnally prefer to have a SHA-1 hashed password than a MD5 one, even if it's salted :-)

Comment: The salted digest should return different values for the same password. Hence, the standard implementation of the JDBCRealm cannot work, because it compares results of the `digest` function during authn.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only way is to make own implementation of few functions (overriding JDBCRealm's methods) such as `authenticate`.